# What is the more performant way to add styles in a mui-Box component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In a mui [Box](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/) component, you can add custom styles using either the prop `sx` or the specific style prop directly.

### Case 1:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    padding: '16px',
    border: '1px solid black',
  }}
>...</Box>
```

### Case 2:

```
<Box
    padding='16px'
    border='1px solid black'
>...</Box>
```

Both ways have the same visual result.

So, I am wondering which is the best way in this case?

Which approach hurts performance less?